# How to Insert Columns Separately

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to have my macro insert columns after certain columns. From what I have read, I'm doing everything correctly, but I'm getting an

> error 1004,

and I haven't found anyone who has had the exact setup as me.

From what I've seen, most people are inserting a column range: `.Range("H:Q")`
I Need to insert separate columns: `.Range(H:H,K:K,N:N,Q:Q)`

What am I doing wrong?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert_Multiple_Columns()
    Dim FIFA As Workbook
    Set FIFA = ActiveWorkbook

    'Ingredient_Forecast_Summary is the sheet name.
    Worksheets("Ingredient_Forecast_Summary").Range("H:H,K:K,N:N,Q:Q").EntireColumn.Insert
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting one column at a time?

Comment: Do it one at a time and start with the furthest right column and work to the left.

Comment: I have to wonder why you declare a workbook var, set it to activeworkbook and then never use it.

Comment: You don't have a *Ingredient_Forecast_Summary* worksheet in the active workbook. Simple as that. Misspelling, leading or trailing space, space instead of the underscore, etc. Perhaps you are confusing ActiveWorkbook with ThisWorkbook. The actual reason the *Ingredient_Forecast_Summary* worksheet cannot be found is unclear from this side of things. It's probably one of the above issues but it could be another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Fine For Now

What Jeeped meant was you should do something like this with your code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Insert_Multiple_Columns()

  Dim wbFIFA As Workbook
  Dim wsIFS As Worksheet

  Set wbFIFA = ActiveWorkbook
  Set wsIFS = wbFIFA.Worksheets("Ingredient_Forecast_Summary")
  'Remarks
  '  Now you can use wsIFS instead of:
  '    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets ("Ingredient_Forecast_Summary")
  '    wbFIFA.Worksheets ("Ingredient_Forecast_Summary")

  wsIFS.Range("H:H,K:K,N:N,Q:Q").EntireColumn.Insert
  'Remarks
  '  The previous line has actually inserted the columns from the right to the
  '  left i.e.
  '  H:H gives you the H column
  '  K:K gives you the L column
  '  N:N gives you the P column
  '  Q:Q gives you the T column

End Sub
```

I created your scenario on my computer, and both codes worked just fine.

### Later

When I deliberately misspelled the name of your worksheet, the error message was 'Subscript out of range (Error 9)'.

When I opened another workbook which then became the ActiveWorkbook and started the sub, the error message was 'Subscript out of range (Error 9)' again.

Then I changed the attributes of the workbook to read-only (stupid idea), but still only could get 'Error 9'.

And then I stumbled upon a scenario that gave me your 'error 1004', namely I protected the worksheet and when I ran the code you know what happened.

I hope this is the reason for your grief. If not, at least some possible reasons have been eliminated.

Comment: Hey VBasic, This makes sense to me, but I'm still running into the 1004 with your code. The sheet is not protected, and not read-only. It still points to the line with the actual insert command as the problem.

Comment: Thx for the points, man, I 've stumbled upon a 1004 today and cannot solve it. I'll post a question and see where it gets me. Then I'll get back to you I guess in a couple of days.